# Regex operation to match a white-space not working

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to make a condition that matches any amount of spaces in a file name `$f`. But what I have seems to be matching everything?

```
if [[ $f =~ [[:space:]]* ]]; then
    echo found a space
fi
```

This matches `i-have-no-spaces.jpg` as well as `i have spaces.jpg`

Comment: `[[:space:]]*` will always find a match, in any string, as it is "allowed" to match **0** chars due to `*`.

Comment: IMHO, I think its more of a `bash` specific usage than a general regex dup (i.e. glob vs regex operator usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `*`, it means 0 or more matches.

Use

```
if [[ $f =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then
    echo "found a space"
fi
```

However in BASH, I suggest to not to use regex for this, just use **glob matching** with `=`:

```
if [[ $f = *[[:space:]]* ]]; then
    echo "found a space"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, sanity returned! Stupid mistake. I realise now this also works: `$f =~ [[:space:]]+`

Comment: There is no need to specify a repetition if you only care if there is at least one.

Comment: @tripleee is right, you can just use `$f =~ [[:space:]]+` as written in my answer also.